# Marketing cloud connector issue - connector breaking in one direction

Tags: marketing-cloud

EDIT: The API user I was using in MC did not have access to it's grandparents BU, which would mean that it doesn't have access to the BU in red. Is this potentially the problem?

I have successfully configured and set up the Marketing Cloud connector in both directions. Last night, my journeys stopped firing.

I have a hierarchy setup in my org which looks like the below:

[image]

The business unit in green is the BU I had configured successfully.

**ISSUE:**
When the BU in red sets up their connection (from the same SFDC, different SF API user), the journeys in my BU (green) stop triggering.

**My theory:**
Because the BU in red is not under the same heirarchy tree as me, does this mean it will not allow for multiple connections?

TLDR; we have multi-org set up.

Thanks for your help in advance!